# Access Nest "injector" in a custom interceptor

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I need to access a service (provided by Nest `TypeOrmModule`) inside the `intercept` function (important note: not as `constructor` parameter!!!) because **it depends of the passed options** (`entity` in this case).

The service injection token is provided by the `getRepositoryToken` function.

```
export class PaginationInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly entity: Function) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, call$: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    // Here I want to inject the TypeORM repository.
    // I know how to get the injection token, but not HOW to
    // get the "injector" itself.
    const repository = getRepositoryToken(this.entity);

    // stuff...

    return call$;
  }
}
```

Is any concept of "service container" in Nest? This [github issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/283) didn't help me.

Example usage (controller action):

```
  @Get()
  @UseInterceptors(new PaginationInterceptor(Customer))
  async getAll() {
    // stuff...
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Regarding **dependency injection** (if you really want/need it), I guess using a `mixin` class can do the trick. See the [v4 documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/v4/advanced/mixins) (Advanced > Mixin classes).

```
import { NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, mixin, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

export function mixinPaginationInterceptor<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(entityClass: T) {
  // declare the class here as we can't give it "as-is" to `mixin` because of the decorator in its constructor
  class PaginationInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor(@Inject(getRepositoryToken(entityClass)) private readonly repository: Repository<T>) {}

    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, $call: Observable<any>) {
      // do your things with `this.repository`
      return $call;
    }
  }

  return mixin(PaginationInterceptor);
}
```

**Disclaimer**: this is valid TypeScript code but I didn't had the chance to test it in a real project, so it might need a bit of rework. The idea is to use it like this:

```
@UseInterceptors(mixinPaginationInterceptor(YourEntityClass))
```

Let me know if you have any question about the code. But I think the doc about `mixin` is pretty good!

---

**OR** You can also use `getRepository` from `typeorm` (passing the entity class). **This is not DI**, thus, it will oblige you to `spyOn` the `getRepository` function in order to do proper testing.

---

Regarding the container, I'm almost sure that the only way to access it is using the [Execution Context](https://docs.nestjs.com/execution-context), as pointed by Kim.

Comment: Very well thanks! That was what I mean. Works, but slightly modified. I can't understand type hints here, and they are not correct (entity class not assignable to `T`, lacks of prototype).... why `<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(entityClass: T)`? And why using `mixin` at all instead of using native typescript `return class`?

Comment: Hey! 

➵ `new (...args: any[]) => any` is somewhat a way to define a "Class type". You can btw see `ClassType` definition in TypeORM exports. This is barely the same but it does not play well with the `Function` type expected by `getRepositoryToken`.

➵ `mixin` automatically declares the given `mixinClass` as `Injectable` (see its code source in nest repo, `component.decorator.ts`)